# Python returns False even if internet is connected

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python. This a script I wrote to check internet connection

```
import os
import urllib2
from time import sleep
REMOTE_SERVER = "www.google.co.uk"

def is_connected():
  try:
    # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is
    # a DNS listening
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
    # reachable
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
     pass
  return False

while(1):
   if is_connected()  == False:
     print is_connected()
   sleep(10)
```

The problem is that this script returns false even if I am connected to internet. I can ping www.google.co.uk but this script simply returns false. Any Ideas???

Comment: In `except` block `print` the exception rather than `pass`ing it

Comment: thats not a good test, even if its not likely to happen, what if google went down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you haven't imported `socket`, your reference to `socket.gethostbyname` will fail with a NameError. But you're catching and silencing *every single exception* in your try/except block, including that very error. You should never ever do a blank except in the first place, and especially never just to have `pass`.

Remove that try/except, or limit it to exceptions you know you can handle.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, never do this:

```
try:
    something()
except:
    pass
```

Which is the Python equivalent of the good'ol Visual Basic [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), if you recall:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Leading to unmaintainable and impossible to debug code. Simply because when a problem arises, you don't know what happened (and you don't even know that there is any problem at all).

In your particular case, I suggest you **remove the try/except block** so that you can know which exception is raised in the traceback. Then, you'll be able to fix it.

Comment: Thanks since I moved from C# i was used to using Try Catch in Visual Studio with breakpoints but I will remember your suggestion for future.